# How much Java should a Web Design team member know?

Tags: software-development

We have a Java/Web team with several Java developers and a web designer.   The "developers" handle everything from the database layer up to the sending of pages to the browser (using JSP pages).   The "designer" is responsible for image creation, skinning the pages using CSS and tweaking the JSP pages to make them look "right".

Unfortunately this division of responsibility leaves a gap between the "developers" and the "designer."    For example, Javascript tasks tend to get kicked back and forth.   The developers say that it's a browser thing, therefore it should be the designer's job, and the designer counters that it's programming, therefore it's the developer's job.

Another problem is source control - our designer, after several years, still refuses to do merges in Git.   He typically will put his code in a feature branch and send an email to the development team saying "branch so-and-so is ready to merge."

This problem could probably be solved with some simple guidelines like "All team members should perform their own source control maintenance" or similar general rules.   But we don't have any.

What are the general rules that could be applied in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. This question appears to be more about job descriptions or technical skills than about project management within the scope defined in our help center. If your question is closed, you can rewrite the question so that it is more about process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the front-end developer/designer job is to create visual design of the website, slice it and develope the javascript, jquery,html and CSS then s/he's done; as there is no way s/he'd be familiar with all the programming language out there to be able to integrate the output into the target website.Unless s/he volunteered to learn it of course.

Then the developer should integrate the output because s/he's more aware of the used language which is JSP in this case.

**What about pair-programming**? I think if you tried to have the developer and the designer work together on one or two screen(s),then they'll share the knowledge they have and avoid future conflicts because they'd understand each other work better then hopefully the gap will shrink somehow.

Regarding the git issue, most of the designers I worked with have the same issue. Git is not a very easy tool for them to use, usually we keep searching for plugins or scripts to make the process of committing their work easier for them.

I suggest that you talk with your team and understand why the tool is bugging the designer and try to figure a way to solve it. If there is no solution then you should start define some guideline/policies and all the team should adhere to it equally.

Thanks!